# Why not use random world events instead of a proof-of-work algorithm?

Tags: proof-of-work

Taking a combination of world events-- thunder, astronomical imagery, vote outcomes, stock index value-- and deriving the ID of the source of truth from a hashed combination of them could be used instead of a proof-of-work algorithm. Why isn't it used?

Comment: The good thing with a proof of work is that you can verify it on your own though. Hard to know world events without trusting anybody

Comment: I looked into pulsars as a source for this. It's theoretically possible to use multiple overlapping pulsar waveforms as a random source but the equipment required to make observations is costly and cumbersome, which is very problematic.

Answer (score 11):

A true source of randomness or a Common Reference String (CRS) as it's referred to in cryptography, could potentially be used in some cases in the place of Proof-of-Work, although as [forest pointed out](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/58623/7195) it isn't immediately clear how to achieve this or whether it is possible, especially in settings such as blockchains where something closer to a Random Oracle (RO) [is needed](https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/765.pdf). However, it may be possible to substitute the two in settings such as Proof-of-Stake, like [Ouroboros](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/889.pdf) is doing. In the latter case, because of the design of the system, a CRS is not really needed – the participants can generate their randomness locally.

However, for the sake of argument, I will now describe some reasons for which using the types of events you mentioned as a CRS is inappropriate for designing cryptographically secure decentralized systems.

1. **Public verifiability**. It is easy for any machine to locally verify proof of work in polynomial time. If you give a piece of proof of work to a mobile phone or a laptop, they can check to make sure it has been computed correctly. However, they cannot do so for thunders, unless they constantly monitor the earth. Public verifiability means that anyone can verify, even after the fact.
2. **Consensus**. Participants can easily *agree* on whether a piece of proof-of-work is correct. The condition is clear and well-defined. However, for real world events, this may not be so. For instance, there are weird physical phenomena which may be considered thunder by some scientists and not by others, or a thunder may be captured by one observer, but not by others, even if they are actively monitoring for such events. This disagreement can break consensus protocols which require that all participants agree.
3. **Sustainability**. Proof-of-work is a system which will continue to work ad infinitum, because it is based on a mathematical formula. Systems such as stock indices may not. Stock exchanges close down and indices are redefined or sunset. While these events may be rare, if we are building the economy of the future which we want to last for more than a hundred years, we want a system that can continue to function regardless of such changes. If these changes do happen and we rely on them instead of proof-of-work, we would have to redefine our systems every time a change happened, and such a redefinition would require making difficult consensus decisions (which can lead to forks in the case of blockchains).
4. **Centralization**. It is difficult to define an objective *source of truth* for the values of these events. If the source of truth is defined as, say, the stock exchange website, then the central party that runs the website can manipulate the values that are displayed there. This makes the system prone to centralized manipulation. For instance, a court can order the exchange website to display false data in order to subvert the system.
5. **Distribution**. It is difficult to say what kind of distribution is followed by various sources of randomness such as the stock market. The fact that the stock market is [just a random walk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk_hypothesis) is controversial, and using this hypothesis to ensure our economy's future is an incorrect approach, especially because we cannot quantify it and prove our claims. While there exist [ways to extract good randomness from skewed randomness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomness_extractor), some quantification of the entropy in the source is needed, for which we also have a limited understanding.
6. **Manipulation**. This is related to the last two points above. Some of the systems you are proposing may be possible to manipulate by participants, given enough incentives. For example, if I am a rich investor, I could buy or sell a particular stock to change the value of the index, skewing the randomness in a particular predictable manner. If this artificial biasing is something I can use in my favour to make more money than I need to invest to cause the skewing, then it may be rational to act in that manner. It is difficult to give a game theoretic argument that such acts are impossible. With proof-of-work, the outcome cannot be artificially manipulated.

Comment: Ad 1. let's forget the thunders, although I can think of a consensus algorithm, that solves this problem.

Comment: How would you publicly verify the stock market prices from, say, a smartphone?

Comment: Ad2. Consensus protocol is an algorithm, that has to bee agreed upon, therefore it is open to discussion. What I mean is that it does not need to be rigid. For example - if 80% of participants agree - then OK. Ad 3. again - a matter of algorithm and voting. From time to time  a new source of random truth will be discovered proposed to the network and accepted. Also other sources might get voted out.  Ad4 Ad5 Ad6 We should use as many sources as possible add them and hash.

Comment: I think it is not about verification of one stock market. it should be the verification of as many of them as possible. And then it can be done via on-line services

Comment: @MatthiasDanetzky You bring up many issues. I will answer them in separate comments. (1) Regarding the use of online services for checking the stock market. This brings in a centralized trusted third party, which can be subpoenaed by a court. Even if we use multiple parties here, it still forms a "cothority" (collaborative authority) and all of them could be subpoenaed. This may be OK for some systems depending on your threat model, but is a weaker result than a completely decentralized system.

Comment: (2) Regarding the use of 80% of the participants for agreement. This proposal seems to be [Sybil attackable](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/50922/whats-a-sybil-attack/50923#50923) in the sense that I could create many fake identities that seem like separate identities from the outside and then outvote the rest of the participants. This is exactly the kind of problem that proof-of-work is trying to solve (by counting CPU power instead of counting people).

Comment: (3) Regarding using many sources, adding them, and then hashing them together. This could be a bad idea because the system can be manipulated as long as any one of the sources can be manipulated after the value of the others has been determined. Imagine a system that uses thunders and the stock market together. If the thunder is truly random, but the stock market is manipulatable, if the thunder data is available prior to the stock market data, then the stock market can be manipulated based on the thunder data so that certain randomness can be yielded.

Comment: (1) They can be subpoenaed if we are talking about one or a few jurisdictions. I was thinking about world wide Stock exchanges (in all jurisdictions we can think of) which makes it virtually impossible to get subpoenaed without a world conflict.

Comment: (2) True, but there are more reliable algorithms. This was just an example

Comment: (3) True, this is why I'm currently working on a system, that does not rely on this sort of data.

Comment: (1) A world stock exchange can be subpoenaed without significant world effects. In particular, if a specific blockchain implementation relies on a certain centralized stock exchange service, such as a website, and parses the output of the stock exchange in a predictable manner, the stock exchange can be subpoenaed to add the text "The following prices are inaccurate and have been demanded by court", after listing the specially crafted data, which can be used to bring down the blockchain before they have a chance to react. Such manipulability is undesirable in decentralized systems.

Comment: (2) Could you give a concrete example?

Comment: (3) What kind of data sources are you using?

Comment: (2)(3) We are currently working on a consensus algorithm whereby all participants are constantly proposing cryptographically signed and numbered in sequence random numbers. At a particular moment the hashes of all of those random numbers are added. The outcome of addition is hashed again. This hash is a ubiquitous and agreeable source of randomness.

Comment: @MatthiasDanetzky I'd be curious to see your scheme once you have a writeup. My concerns would be two-fold: (1) how to secure against the participants choosing their randomness based on the randomness of the others and (2) how to avoid participants aborting in case they see the randomness is not in their favour (causing a further bias if the protocol is re-run). Thanks!

Comment: I'm currently looking for a site to publish it (Any ideas?). Since the outcome of summation is hashed - there is no way to tip the odds in any way by posting rouge random number. The only way to hack it is by controlling 100% of network. Even one free agent will make the outcome 100% unpredictable.

Comment: I'm not sure how hashing would help achieve your claim; I'd love to see your construction detailed to inspect. If you write it in a LaTeX paper PDF format, you can simply put it up [on eprint](https://eprint.iacr.org/). Looking forward!

Answer (score 5):

You are misunderstanding what a proof-of-work algorithm is designed to accomplish. It's designed to provide an economic disincentive to repeating the process many times (e.g. sending an email or visiting a website). Real-world values on the other hand have the distinct property of being difficult to predict in advance, making it useful for proving that a given document was not created before a certain date (for example). There is no way to use that property in a proof-of-work system.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Unfortunately the proof-of-work is what is used to choose the miner in the blockchain and I didn't know of any other easy to understand name for the 'miner choice' problem.

Comment: Proof-of-work for email spam is an entirely different use case to proof-of-work for cryptocurrencies and I don't think your answer applies to cryptocurrencies.